# Thread.interrupt is returing false

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

I was trying out the below code, I interrupted a user thread, when I print the value of isInterrupted it is returning false, I didn't got a single true value, over here the flag will get reset when the exception has been caught or on calling interrupted method.

Secondly, as per my understanding sleep method should throw and interruptedException in each iteration, the value in catch print, but it is throwing only once.

```
class ThreadInterruptt extends Thread
{
    public void run()
    {

        for(int i = 0; i<100;i++)
        {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                System.out.println(i);
                System.out.println(isInterrupted());
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                System.out.println("Thread Interrupted");
            }
        }
    }
}
public class ThreadInterrupt {
    public static void main(String ag[]) throws InterruptedException
    {
        ThreadInterruptt t = new ThreadInterruptt();
        t.start();
        Thread.sleep(100);
        t.interrupt();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You wouldn't ever get to the `isInterrupted()` check if you are interrupted: `Thread.sleep()` would have thrown an exception, and also it clears the interrupted status of the Thread, [as described in the Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)).

And you're then discarding the fact the thread was interrupted (because you don't reset the interrupted flag on catching the exception), so it's not interrupted on the next iteration.

Comment: shouldn't isInterrupted() return true? after t.interrupt();

Comment: @Shelly it would be in between when you call `t.interrupt()` and the next time you invoke `Thread.sleep`. However, `Thread.sleep` clears the interrupted status, as described in the Javadoc.

Comment: I tried printing the value of isInterrupted before ```Thread.sleep``` it returns false; it giving me the true value when I'm interrupting the thread within its code but not when i'm calling interrupt from main method

Comment: @Shelly that'll be because that happens before you interrupt it.

Comment: Yes it helped me now i'm getting the values.

Comment: @Shelly I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210610/discussion-between-shelly-and-andy-turner).

Comment: In principle, there are no guarantees that a thread gets the CPU while being runnable, so even when the main thread does sleep(100) and the other sleep(1000), there is the possibility that the main thread makes no progress within the 900ms after the sleep. In  that case, there is a tiny, really tiny chance of interrupting the other thread between the sleep(1000) and isInterrupted(). In that unlikely corner case, the program would print true once, but the next sleep would still clear the interrupted state.